# Problem wih (diverging?) digital IIR filter for an online acquisition system

Tags: filters, filter-design, python, bandpass, scipy

I am trying to plot windows of acquired data from an LSL-compatible system. For the example below, let's consider 1-second window of a 64 channel EEG system. In practice, I use shorter 0.2-window, but the problematic behavior is present also with 1-second window.

The acquired data is a numpy array of shape `(samples, channels)`, thus in this example, with a 512 Hz sampling frequency: `(512, 64)`.

Before plotting the data, it has to be preprocessed with a bandpass filter. Let's consider a `[1, 40] Hz` bandpass filter:

```
from scipy.signal import butter

lowcut = 1
highcut = 40
fs = 512

low = lowcut / (0.5 * fs)
high = highcut / (0.5 * fs)
sos = butter(4, [low, high], btype='band', output='sos', fs=fs)
```

As each window will be plot on the same expanding graph, the initial and final conditions of each window are required. Thus, the `zi` parameter is passed to `scipy.signal.sosfilt()` to retrieve the `zf` final conditions. The system is initialized with a resting state initial condition.

```
zi = np.zeros((sos.shape[0], 2, n)) # n = 64 - number of channels
```

To filter the data, I then apply:

```
data_filtered, zf = sosfilt(sos, data, 0, zi)
```

I don't see what I am doing wrong, and yet the output is diverging. By the way, I tried order 2, 4 and 6; and it does change the output but still diverge.

Inputted window of 1 channel:

[image: input]

Output window of the same channel:

[image: output]

After some research, I believe I should not specify the `fs` parameter to `scipy.signal.butter()` when passing the cutting frequencies as normalized from 0 to 1, where 1 is the Nyquist frequency. Nevertheless, the output is different but still diverging.

```
sos = butter(2, [1, 40], btype='band', output='sos', analog=False, fs=fs)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your signal has a massive DC bias so your output is dominated by the step response of the band pass filter. It will eventually get there but it's going to take a really long time.

Initialize your state with `zi = -26040*sosfilt_zi()`. See my answer to your other question today.

**EDIT**

On second thought: while you can fix some of this in software, you probably shouldn't. Your DC bias is about 500 times bigger than your actual signal. A bias that large is typically a sign that something went seriously wrong upstream: could be sensor, calibration, analog front end, ADC, digital pre-processing, data acquisition etc.

A large DC bias can cause a lot of trouble. For example:

1. You are loosing 50dB+ of dynamic range
2. If the DC bias drifts by even a tiny amount, the effect will swamp or obscure your desired signal.

Instead of filtering I would recommend trying to identify the root cause of the bias and fix (or improve)it. Processing can only do so much: bad_data_in can only lead to bad_data_out. It might be a little less bad , but it's probably still bad.

Comment: Now it starts to make all sense!! I'll try!

Comment: @Mathieu, sorry, I think I gave you bad advice. Please read the edit. Filtering isn't the right answer here, no matter how you do it.

Comment: Thank you for the additional thoughts. Unfortunately, I can not do much about the DC bias. The system(s) I am using are EEG systems, which are known to have a very large DC bias always. I don't have access to the companies hardware schematics or software of the amplifiers anyway. However, I got the filtering to work on 3-4 consecutive acquisition windows of 200 ms perfectly.